# How to avoid the flash out caused by Javascript latency when page loading on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, frontend, vue.js

When using `Vue.js` or any other `Javascript` to construct a page, the inevitable constructing latency causes transitory but annoying flash out when loading the page on Chrome. The latency doesn't lead by the asynchronous `ajax` request, but just the constructing processing. How can we avoid this? This problem doesn't exist on FireFox and Safari, I guess they don't show the pages until rendering and constructing are completed, but on Chrome, it shows the pages at the same time of rendering and constructing side by side, so you will see the pages are fluctuant, that's really unacceptable. Anyone have good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact problem with this lib, but

Try using css to cover-up items that are being built visibility:hidden or maybe even display:none.
Or to still show some progress but somewhat lessen the effect - screen overlay (top-level div with position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); /* fourth alpha marks how dark the overlay is - the closer to 1 the darker */)